# TYPO3: modify root page of sitemap in plugin tx_seo

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I successfully configured the sitemap of my TYPO3 v10 project within the plugin SEO and added custom configurations in my templatesetup.ts with the [official TYPO3 docs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/XmlSitemap/Index.html):

```
plugin.tx_seo {
  config {
    xmlSitemap {
      sitemaps {
        pages {
          provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\PagesXmlSitemapDataProvider
          config {
            excludedDoktypes = 3, 4, 6, 7, 199, 254, 255
            additionalWhere = no_index = 0
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Here you can see a few lines of my sitemap.xml:

[image: cutout of my sitemap.xml]

My goal is, to remove all the lines with just the root "/". How can I set another rootId for my sitemap.xml other than 1?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the parameter `rootPage`. Unfortunately it's [undocumented](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/XmlSitemap/Index.html) (yet).

So your TypoScript should look like this:

```
plugin.tx_seo {
  config {
    xmlSitemap {
      sitemaps {
        pages {
          provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\PagesXmlSitemapDataProvider
          config {
            excludedDoktypes = 3, 4, 6, 7, 199, 254, 255
            additionalWhere = no_index = 0
            rootPage = 135
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: I've created a pull request to add this parameter to the documentation:
https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/TYPO3CMS-Reference-CoreApi/pull/1104